# Sql binary to c# - How to get SQL binary equivalent of binary in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, binary

It might seem a dumb question to you guys. I have one SQL table with one binary column. It has some data in binary format.

e.g. `0x9A8B9D9A002020202020202020202020`

It's equivalent english representation is `"test".`

Is it possible to convert this `string` into equivalent `binary` form in `c#` ?

```
string s = "test"; // C# code to convert s to it's equivalent SQL binary form.
```

Comment: Depends how it was stored. What process stored it?

Comment: Can you explain how you got to `0x9A8B9D9A002020202020202020202020` from `'test'`? If so, we can probably explain how to go the other way. That isn't a direct translation in any of the conversion mechanisms I'm familiar with. Is it possible this is encrypted or hashed in some way?

Comment: Some kind of algorithm is used I guess. Say 9A -> t, 8B -> e, 9D-> s. So the word formed here is test. This can be done by lookup mechanism. I am just looking if this can be achieved by any in-built mechanism.

Comment: May be I have to see if this translation has any limited scope or not.

Comment: What kind of encoding places `s` 3 characters *beyond* `t` (when `e` seems to be the "correct" distance from `t`)?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static byte[] ConvertToBinary(string str)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```

or

```
Convert.ToByte(string);
```

Comment: that won't be correct 0x9A8B9D9A is not ASCII text for "test"

Comment: No it's not giving the output I am looking for :(

Comment: @VijayBalkawade - will it work if you change to `System.Text.Encoding.Default`?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which encoding was used when you originally converted from string to binary:

```
 byte[] binaryString = (byte[])reader[1];

 // if the original encoding was ASCII
 string x = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(binaryString);

 // if the original encoding was UTF-8
 string y = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binaryString);

 // if the original encoding was UTF-16
 string z = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(binaryString);

 // etc
```